# How do I convert the output of a JSON Dump to a format where I can access the individual elements, and convert it to a datframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the output of a JSON dump:

[image: JSON DUMP]

in str format and I have converted it into  list of lists, using the following code:

```
match=re.findall('\(.*?\)',file) #find the elements between the brackets ( and ) using 
regex,then store it as a list of lists
NewList= [[x] for x in iter(match)] 
  
print("The new lists of lists: ",NewList)
```

This gives the following output:

[image: output]

But now, i can't access the individual elements of the list since the whole list is treated as str, NewList[0][0] gives the first list

[image: Output here]

how do I access the elements inside a list and store them in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

This code snippet might solve your issue:

```
final_list_vals = []
NewList = [["(1086732,'edit','sysop',0,NULL,'infinity',1307)"], ["(1086732,'edit','sysop',0,NULL,'infinity',1307)"]] # This is just a sample input.
for lst in NewList:
    final_list_vals.append(eval(lst[0].replace('NULL', 'None')))

column_lst = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7']
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list_vals, columns=column_lst)
```

**NOTE:** Add column list as per your requirement.

Leave a comment in case it does not solve your purpose.

**OUTPUT:**

```
     col_1 col_2  col_3  col_4 col_5     col_6  col_7
0  1086732  edit  sysop      0  None  infinity   1307
1  1086732  edit  sysop      0  None  infinity   1307
```

Comment: I've tried it and it gave this error:
File "<ipython-input-98-02cc4d6a9693>", line 3, in <module>
    final_list_vals.append(eval(lst[0]))
: File "<string>", line 1 ( ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: can you share sample input string.

Comment: It's "(1086732,'edit','sysop',0,NULL,'infinity',1307)"

Comment: I tried it and it seems like NULL isn't defined in Python so I manually replaced it with None in the input string and it worked, thanks

Comment: I have updated the code, now it will replace all NULL with None before evaluating it. Check if it works.
I have also added sample input so that you can use it as reference